# Importing a Subscribed Calendar into App using Event Kit iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to import a calendar into my iOS app which I am subscribed to. If I use the code:

```
if (currentCalendar.type == EKCalendarTypeSubscription) {
NSLog(@"%@", currentCalendar);
```

The console displays all my calendars including the one I want (I have a loop running). If I use the code:

```
if([currentCalendar.title  isEqual: @"Calendar I want"]){
NSLog(@"%@", currentCalendar);
```

It does not import the canlendar despite copying the name directly from the previous console with all calendars. I have tried this with other subscribed calendars and this does not work but it Does work with non-subscribed calendars. Anyone know whats going on? Many thanks

PS complete method is as follows :)

```
-(NSArray *)getLocalEventCalendars{
NSLog(@"Get Local Event Calendars Method");
NSArray *allCalendars = [self.eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
NSMutableArray *localCalendars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<allCalendars.count; i++) {
    EKCalendar *currentCalendar = [allCalendars objectAtIndex:i];
if([currentCalendar.title  isEqual: @"Calendar I want"]){
        NSLog(@"%@", currentCalendar);
        [localCalendars addObject:currentCalendar];
    }
}

return (NSArray *)localCalendars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this in the end, i converted the currentalendar.title into a string and then checked that and it worked fine, odd.